# Encrypt data with RSA public key in Java and decrypt in Crypto++

Tags: java, c++, interop, rsa, crypto++

I'm trying to encrypt data with RSA public key in Java and decrypt it in Crypto++. It results in an error:

> "RSA/EME-PKCS1-v1_5: ciphertext length of 24 doesn't match the required length of 128 for this key"

What am I doing wrong?

***Java***:

```java
String cipher = Encryption.encryptStrRSA(txt, pubKeyk);

public static String encryptStrRSA(String str, PublicKey pubKey)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
    IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

    byte[] encryptedAesKey = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    String cipherStr = new String(encryptedAesKey);

    System.out.println(cipherStr);
    return cipherStr;
}

public static PublicKey strToPublicKey(String key64) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key64);
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return fact.generatePublic(spec);
}

public static String publicKeyToStr(PublicKey publ) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = fact.getKeySpec(publ, X509EncodedKeySpec.class);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encode(spec.getEncoded()).toString();
}
```

***Crypto++***:

```c++
using namespace CryptoPP;

RSAES_PKCS1v15_Decryptor priv(privString);
StringSource( cipher, cipherSize, true, new 
Base64Decoder( new PK_DecryptorFilter(randPool, priv, new StringSink(sdata))));
```

Comment: `byte[] encryptedAesKey = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
            String cipherStr = new String(encryptedAesKey);`
This has no chance of working, and makes no sense at all.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong..."* - we need to see how you are saving the cipher text in Java, and how you are loading it in Crypto++. My guess is all the cipher text is *not* being written in Java, or all of it is *not* being loaded in Crypto++. Be careful with C++ `std::string`. Some constructors stop at the first `NULL` character.

Comment: is everything OK? how do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to use String instances for keeping binary data -- you should use byte[] instead.

Additionally, in the java code there is no Base64 wrapping of the resulting ciphertext, but in the C++ code it is being unwrapped from Base64.

Modified your code to return byte[] and encode the result using Base64:

```
public static byte[] encryptRSA(String str, PublicKey pubKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
}

String cipher = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Encryption.encryptRSA("0123456789ABCDEF", pubKeyk));
```

Then you can decrypt in Crypto++ the same way you did.

Good luck!